# How do I arrange photos by visual similarities?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a software to arrange and view all my 30k pictures by similarities. Definitely I won't tag them one by one!

I was looking for something similar to *visolu2* (an iPad app), or something like *piximilar* - but for hard drive.
*ImageSorter* (a software made by the same people of *visolu2*) does the job, but I can only run it with Wine + is no longer supported. I would prefer a software for Linux.
All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

[ImgSeek](http://www.imgseek.net/) is an open-source solution that will let you search by similarity and even sketch a basic version of the photo you're looking for.

I'm not sure that the huge display of images by dominant colour is a feature, but it should do almost everything else you need. It's also being actively developed so this feature may be added in future.

The screenshot below shows searching for similar images.

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of _ImgSeek_, but it doesn't display all photos as you said. Thanks anyway!